# Ng-model not working

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ngmodel, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular google map API. I want to clear the searchbox inputfield when I press a button.

HTML

```
<ui-gmap-search-box options="searchbox.options" template="searchbox.template" events="searchbox.events" position="searchbox.position" ng-model="searchModel.searchTerm"></ui-gmap-search-box>

<md-button class="md-icon-button searchbutton" ng-click="toggleSearch()" md-ink-ripple="false" aria-label="Custom Icon Button">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/search.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
```

JS

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function () {

        var searchFieldInput = document.getElementById('pac-input')
        if (searchFieldInput.classList.contains('searchactive')) {
            searchFieldInput.classList.remove('searchactive')



        } else {
            searchFieldInput.classList.add('searchactive')
        }

        $scope.searchModel.searchTerm = null;

    }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: have you any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Initializing search template via `ui-gmap-search-box` directive creates a new child scope so `$scope.searchModel.searchTerm` isn't getting changed.

**Solution**

Replace `toggleSearch` function with:

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function() {
   var searchFieldInput = document.getElementById('pac-input')
   var scope = angular.element(searchFieldInput).scope(); //get scope for ui-gmap-search-box
   scope.searchModel.searchTerm = "";
}
```

**Working example**

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iv4jfzLocrB8fkUFvYuA?p=preview)